# Exit from a loop in php in a wordpress envirnoment

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops

I'm developing a tool to display some members on a page in wordpress.I hard coded most of the parts but I'm taking advantage of the database, inserting a section where I'm running the loop. Now I want to use both the loop and a jQuery plugin called flipster (https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster) to nicely display a carousel that will display each of them. So far so good, the only thing is that I'm not able to end the loop. My code is the following:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <ul class="flip-items">
        <li>
            <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
            <?php query_posts("cat=2"); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php $socialaddress = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
                if ( ! empty( $socialaddress ) ) {
                    echo '<h4>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) . '</h4>' ;
                } ?>
                <?php $socialaddress = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Company', true );
                if ( ! empty( $socialaddress ) ) {
                    echo '<h6>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Company', true) . '</h6>' ;
                } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php 
            $counter++;
            if ($counter % 1 == 0) {
                echo '<li>';
            }
            if ($counter == false) {
                echo '</li>';
            }
            endwhile; 
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can notice, my loop will end but the last element will open another li item, so I will mess up my layout. Is there any way to prevent that behavior?

UPDATE:

The website where I put the plugin is the following: (http://larchedev.com/pip/) .
As you can notice right after the last li item, it is opened another li which doesn't contain anything since I put a certain number of members.

Comment: `break;` exits a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try indenting your code to see clearer what is happening.

Why do you this:

```
$counter++;
if ($counter % 1 == 0) {
    echo '<li>';
}
if ($counter == false) {
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Your $counter is not initialized, your $counter % 1 will always result $counter. 
Couldn't understand what are you trying to achieve here.

Anyway, why don't you put the "

" items like this:

```
echo '<li><h4>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) . '</h4></li>' ;
```

Then you won't need those 2 strange IF's anymore. Not even to break the while loop, since it will stop when were no more posts.

Comment: I actually used the first part for all my loops in wordpress:
<?php 
            $counter++;
            if ($counter % 1 == 0) {
                echo '<li>';
            }

            endwhile; 
        ?>
The thing is that I tried to figure it out the second part to exit from the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit a loop. Or you can use `continue` to skip the current iteration of the loop.

```
<?php 
     $temp_query = $wp_query;
     while (have_posts()) : 
      ....         
         if ( /* some condition here */ ) { 
             break; //this will exit your loop, you decide where to put it
         }
      ....
     endwhile;
?>
```